# How to configure wordpress website emails for Exim?

Tags: wordpress, email, configuration, exim4

The website is hosted in an Exim enabled server. So wordpress default email functioning doesn't work there. If I am to configure, the website to send mails using Exim via smtp, what do i need to do?
Any guidance for that ?